# Serving a custom featured image for mobile

Tags: metabox, post-thumbnails, mobile, add-theme-support

is it a good approach to serve multiple featured images to have a proper scaling?

Right now the featured image size on "`Desktop`" is up to 1140x250. Pretty wide and will shrink way too far on "`Mobile 1`", until you can't really recognize the image anymore.

My idea was to just serve a second featured image for mobile phones up to like 500px. The size of this "`Mobile 2`" featured image would be something like 500x250.

**Pro**: Ability to serve different images on mobile/desktop and crop/scale ourselves.
**Con**: Every image needs to be uploaded and edited twice.

Is there a WordPress native way to do this I completely missed?
[image: Mobile Featured Image Example]

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with Advanced Custom Fields and a [Sass mixin](https://gist.github.com/brz0/5689c1891450cd820706f3698fc84d67#file-sass-mixin-retina-image-scss):

```
@mixin image-2x($image, $width, $height) {
  @media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
         (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
         (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
         (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
         (min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {
    background-image: url($image);
    background-size: $width $height;
  }
}
//Usage
div.logo {
  background: url("logo.png") no-repeat;
  @include image-2x("logo2x.png", 100px, 25px);
}
```

Featured images or native custom fields could also be used instead of ACF. For an automatic solution that removes the need to upload multiple image versions you can use a retina plugin - [WP Retina 2x](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/).